# How to render background for each section in SectionList component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-sectionlist

How to render the background for each section?

```js
<SectionList
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
  sections={list}
  renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.name}</Text>}
  renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => {
    return (
        <View bg-bg6ColorLabel style={{ width: 170, borderRadius: 500, alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: 20 }}>
          <Text textColor style={{ textAlign: 'center', padding: 7, fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 16 }}>{section.titleWithDay}</Text>
        </View>
    )
  }}
/>
```

I want to have background under each item of section.

Answer (score 0):

Just like this:

```js
<SectionList
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
  sections={list}
  renderItem={props => {
                if (props.index < 1) {
                  return (
                      <View>
                        <FlatList
                            data={props.section.data}
                            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                                <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                            )}
                        />
                      </View>
                  );
                } else {
                  return null;
                }
              }}
  renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => {
    return (
        <View >
          <Text>{section.titleWithDay}</Text>
        </View>
    )
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).